# How to end curl command

Tags: bash, shell-script, rhel, curl, wget

I want to execute a curl command

```
curl "https://172%40-34%40-40%40-66.cl-api-tst.pod.dcr.non-prod.ichp.ing.net:8443/xyz/bla-bla/search/"
```

but this command never ends and execute the terminal still expects some input from me.
I am executing this on RHEL Server and curl version `curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`
The same command works locally on Git Bash. Also if i give wrong url it gives me right error `curl: (6) Could not resolve host:`. but with the right host it never executes expect more input, i tried different combinations like with without quotes, but nothing works.

how can i force curl command to end and execute ?

Comment: I've just tried this and it took about 10-15 seconds to fail to resolve the hostname. My guess would be that in your instance it's taking a similar length of time or maybe longer.

Comment: What's that `%40` doing in the hostname? That's urlencoded `@`, which is an ASCII character not allowed in hostnames (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname).

Comment: What does `nslookup "172%40-34%40-40%40-66.cl-api-tst.pod.dcr.non-prod.ichp.ing.net"` return?